# Laravel Raw Query DB::select

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

am using raw query in Laravel and from their documentation this is a sample

```
public function index()
{
    $user = 1;
    $users = DB::select('select * from units where id not in(select unit_id from course where user_id = ? [$user] ));


}
```

if i replace the variable in the query with a number like 1, it returns correct results, BUT i want to use a variable, which would be changing, but cant find a way to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think they missed a few chars and it should be:

```
$user = 1;
$users = DB::select('select * from units where id not in (select unit_id from course where user_id = ?)', [$user]));
```

Almost anywhere in laravel it is working that way. You pass your values as an array as a second parameter to the function.

Comment: If it works then please accept my answer ;-) You could write a comment here if you should have any furher questions.